# Formatting currency without decimals

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am using `LSEuroCurrencyFormat` like this:

```
#LSEuroCurrencyFormat("1999","Local")#
```

which outputs something like:

```
1.999,00 €
```

But what I need is that the decimal part should not be displayed or should not be the part of the price after formatting. It should just look like this:

```
1.999 €
```

Comment: My o/p is $1,999.00. Are you sure about your first output?

Comment: It's locale-specific, Anit. What's your locale? For example I'm in the UK so I get £1,999.00. The "Euro" in that function name is incorrect, as far as I can tell.

Comment: There'll not be an out-of-the-box way to do this in CFML. If you def know that your decimal separator will be `,`, you can go Dan's route. However also looking @ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html might give you a more general/robust solution

Comment: Adam, irrespective of the euro, it will go by the default locale.

Comment: *My o/p is $1,999.00.* Anit - I know that behavior is noted in the documentation, but ... I am not sure I see the point. Why display euro's with the local currency symbol? That kind of gives the false impression that the euros were converted into local units (in this case dollars) which of course they are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function uses the standard java rules for formatting [Currency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html), which *usually* implies two decimal places. As @Adam mentioned, there is nothing built in that will give you that exact result. However, you can use [java's number formatting classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html), with a custom [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html), for a more robust solution.

For example, you could use the [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance-java.util.Locale-) class to grab a currency formatter for the appropriate Locale. Then use its methods to suppress the decimal places. (Obviously, that may result in rounding, depending on the input value.) I do not know the default [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) for your JVM, but was able to produce the desired result using the Locale for Spain, ie `es_ES`

```
// Grab currency formatter for the desired Locale
locale = createObject("java", "java.util.Locale").init("es", "ES");
formatter = createObject("java", "java.text.NumberFormat").getCurrencyInstance(locale);

// Suppress decimal places 
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
writeDump( formatter.format( javacast("double", 1999)) );
```

The result is:

```
1.999 €
```

Just keep in mind that java's predefined number and date formats are based on the standard conventions for whatever Locale is used. That includes details like the decimal separator, the currency symbol - even the placement of the currency symbol. While you can change the format however you wish, it is generally best to keep it within the realm of the average user's expectations.